# How can I fix linq query to select count of ids with group by?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, count, group-by, linq-to-entities

I want to create this SQL query to linq:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(m.FromUserId) AS Messages,
    m.FromUserId AS UserId
FROM    
    dbo.ChatMessages m
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ChatMessagesRead mr ON mr.ChatMessageId = m.ChatMessageId
WHERE   
    m.ToUserId = @toUserId
GROUP BY 
    m.FromUserId
```

I have tried create following linq query:

```
var messages = from m in _dbContext.ChatMessages
               join mread in _dbContext.ChatMessagesRead on m.ChatMessageId equals mread.ChatMessageId
               where m.ToUserId == userId
               group m by m.FromUserId into g
               select new
                      {
                         UserId = g.Key,
                         Messages = g.Count()
                      };

var messagesList = messages.ToList();
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I fix this linq query?

I get this exception:

> Expression of type 'System.Func`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages,Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessagesRead],System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages,Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessagesRead],System.Int32]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages]] _GroupBy[<>f__AnonymousType1`2,Int32,ChatMessages](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages,Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessagesRead]], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages,Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessagesRead],System.Int32], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages,Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessagesRead],Project.BL.ChatMessages.ChatMessages])'"

Comment: Are you sure you have records in your db table for that user ? your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Shyju I've updated my question with the exception which I got. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the code for the entities? Maybe there is a minor issue that causes this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue and I've found that there is an opened issue on the [Entity Framework Core bugtracker](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4786)

The only workaround for now seems to split the request in two.

```
var filtered = (from m in _dbContext.ChatMessages
                join mread in _dbContext.ChatMessagesRead on m.ChatMessageId equals mread.ChatMessageId
                where m.ToUserId == userId
               select m).ToList();

var messages = from m in filtered
               group m by m.FromUserId into g
               select new
                  {
                     UserId = g.Key,
                     Messages = g.Count()
                  };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
var res = ctx.MyTable  // Start with your table
        .GroupBy(r => r.id) / Group by the key of your choice
        .Select( g => new {Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}) // Create an anonymous type w/results
        .ToList(); // Convert the results to List
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. However I created another version of your query using extension methods.

```
var messages =
    _dbContext
        .ChatMessages
        .Where(message => message.ToUserId == userId)
        .Join(
            _dbContext.ChatMessageRead,
            message => message.ChatMessageId,
            readMessage => readMessage.ChatMessageId,
            (m, mr) => m.FromUserId
        )
        .GroupBy(id => id)
        .Select(group =>
            new
            {
                UserId = group.Key,
                Messages = group.Count()
            }
        );
```

Could you please try it if it also throws the same exception or not?

Comment: This code return the exception:Expression of type 'System.Func`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer],System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]] _GroupBy[Int32,Int32,Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Int32], System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Int32])'